# Gallery only displaying selected pictures

Tags: android, gallery

I'm working on Android 2.3.6 and 2.3.1 .

I have an unwanted behavior with `Gallery` : sides pictures from Gallery Items won't display.

My Gallery take all the space available and the layout containing the `ImageView` and a `TextView` is set to `WRAP_CONTENT` but still occupies all the screen, so sides items are over the bounds...

Here is the gallery's xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:a="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    a:layout_width="match_parent"
    a:layout_height="match_parent"
    a:layout_margin="0dp"
    a:padding="0dp">

    <ImageView
        a:id="@+imagePopup/selected"
        a:layout_width="60dp"
        a:layout_height="35dp"
        a:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        a:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        a:src="@drawable/ic_cancel"
        a:contentDescription="@string/lng" />
    <TextView
        a:id="@+imagePopup/title"
        a:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        a:layout_toRightOf="@+imagePopup/selected"
        a:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="true"
        a:layout_width="match_parent"
        a:layout_height="35dp"
        a:background="@drawable/rounded"
        a:text="dynamic text"
        a:textSize="23dp"
        a:textColor="#ffffffff"
        a:gravity="center"
        style="@style/trad"/>
    <Gallery
        a:id="@+imagePopup/gallery"
        a:layout_width="match_parent"
        a:layout_height="match_parent"
        a:layout_below="@+imagePopup/title"
        a:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="true"
        a:background="#ff000000"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

and its content xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:a="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    a:layout_width="wrap_content"
    a:layout_height="wrap_content"
    a:background="#ffff55ee">

    <ImageView
        a:id="@+imageContent/imageView"
        a:layout_width="wrap_content"
        a:layout_height="wrap_content"
        a:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        a:padding="0dp"
        a:layout_margin="0dp"
        a:src="@drawable/ic_cancel" />

    <TextView
        a:id="@+imageContent/textOver"
        a:layout_width="wrap_content"
        a:layout_height="wrap_content"
        a:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        a:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        a:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        a:shadowColor="#FF000000"
        a:shadowRadius="4"
        a:textColor="#ffffffff"
        a:textSize="16dp"
        a:textStyle="bold" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I put an ugly background color to the picture container's background (`RelativeLayout`) to show how it behave :

[image: gallery display]

can someone tells me what i'm doing wrong in here... i just can't get rid of it.

Thanks in advance ^^

Comment: android:spacing="5dp" try this Gallery attribute

Comment: spacing on Gallery does nothing (already tried and just tried again...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the probelm is with your Image. You are trying to display a huge image which is more likely to cover the entire screen.

You have to provide some pre defined width and height attributes for your Image.

Instead of wrap_content what you have provided like the one below,

```
  <ImageView
        a:id="@+imageContent/imageView"
        a:layout_width="wrap_content"
        a:layout_height="wrap_content"
        a:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        a:padding="0dp"
        a:layout_margin="0dp"
        a:src="@drawable/ic_cancel" />
```

Try to provide it something like this,

```
  <ImageView
    a:id="@+imageContent/imageView"
    a:layout_width="150dip"
    a:layout_height="150dip"
    a:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    a:padding="0dp"
    a:layout_margin="0dp"
    a:src="@drawable/ic_cancel" />
```

**NOTE:** The layout width and height I have specified here is just imaginary. You have to provide your own.

And you have to know the difference between wrap_content, fill_parent and actual hard coded width and height.

1. Wrap_cotent - It means that, it will use the width and height of your actual image.
2. fill_parent - Whatever maybe the size of your image , it takes the whole screen.
3. Providing height and width by our own means, what ever may be the size of the image you make it to be displayed uniformly by providing a particular width and height attribute.

Comment: trying your hint, but it would be the worst behavior I ever seen... since the height fits automatically, and the width stays proportional, why would the wrapped container stay this big ?? just non-sense...

Comment: many thanks, i posted the solution i found thanks to you just below.

Answer (score 1):

Finally i found a much better way of doing this, more 'natural' as i needed :
here is the modified part of my code :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:a="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    a:layout_width="wrap_content"
    a:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:ignore="ContentDescription">

    <ImageView
        a:id="@+imageContent/imageView"
        a:layout_width="wrap_content"
        a:layout_height="match_parent"
        a:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        a:scaleType="fitXY"
        a:adjustViewBounds="true"
        a:src="@drawable/ic_cancel" />
```

`scaleType="fitXY"` and `adjustViewBounds="true"` made it in no time, thanks to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10123830/android-imageview-scaletype-and-item-height)