# ImageView scaleType

Tags: android, android-imageview, scale

This is my `ImageView` in app (1)
[image]

When I change size of container (`LinearLayout` for example) my `ImageView` change image size but border of view remained the same(2).

How I can set scaling for `ImageView` size and borders? (3)

My `ImageView` code in xml:

```
 <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/cover" />
```

P.S. This is my problem in my app - 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find - [stackoverflow.com/a/10124018/3871859](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10124018/3871859) from here.

My `ImageView` xml:

```
<ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:src="@drawable/cover" />
```

I just add this line:

```
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
```